# How to automate the creation of advanced layout article/post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I try to describe my needs to know what would you suggest me.

Every morning I have to read 10 Newsapers.
Then I have to resume all the Economical topics in many articles (like forex, gas price, gold prevision and so on). Each article includes my analysis and numerous quotations. At the sides (left and right) of text I also need to show sidenotes and specific icon (icons of the newspaper that I am quoting at that line).

[image]

Now, I cannot paginate each article as if it were a simple article, because it would take too much energy in pagination.

The ideal solution for me would be an article composer where I can add predetermined block to the article for different types of text section: analysis, citation and sidenotes with icon, image and description, images.
In this way I would have not to think about layout and styles for each part of the article: I would have just to add a block type and add text content and chose from dropdownmenu (choosing the Name of the Newspaper quoted, date, and Newspaper logo).

In other words, I would need a article composer with a mask, where I can insert text and choose from predetermined values (icon, sidenotes, logos date and so on), to standardize the article composition. Without thinking about layout, styles and pagination.

Is there an instrument to implement this solution in Wordpress?
What solution would you suggest me?

many thanks

Luke

Comment: Custom blocks would work well for this purpose, and if you want you could create a custom post type with a block template for it. If you aren't comfortable coding much, you could look into block patterns instead.

Comment: many thanks! !!!